# Mongo collection is accessible via mongosh (mongo shell) but not nodejs script

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongo-shell

Running the mongod process in the background, in the mongo shell (mongosh), I have the wikipedia database loaded in my database "enwiki". So in the shell, I can just type `db.pages.find()`, and it will show me some pages from Wikipedia. Similarly, if I call `db.getCollectionNames()`, it returns ['pages']. `db.getCollection("pages").find()` also works.

However, if I go to my nodejs script, `db.collection("pages").find()` has nothing in it.

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
const dbName = 'enwiki';
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
client.connect().then(client => {
 console.log('Connected successfully to server');
 const db = client.db(dbName);
 const cursor = db.collection("pages").find();
 cursor.forEach(doc => { console.log(doc.plaintext);});
});
```

Running the above code just prints 'Connected successfully to server' and stops. (It should also print the plaintext of all my Wikipedia articles in my database.)

I'm new to mongo, so I feel like I'm missing something obvious. The database was originally created using [dumpster-dive](https://github.com/spencermountain/dumpster-dive). Calling `db.listCollections()` returns this in the node debugger:

```
{ _events: Object,
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: 'undefined',
  parent: Db,
  filter: Object,
  ... }
```

That object does not contain the pages collection that I am expecting. How do I access the pages collection?

EDIT 1/18/22 (next day): Ran it today not in the debugger and it just worked. For some reason, running `db.collection("pages").find()` and `db.collection("pages").find().limit(1)` in the node debugger returns a similarly weird object to the one above. On the other hand, running `cursor.forEach(doc => { console.log(doc.plaintext);});` in the node debugger just returns:

```
{ [[PromiseState]]: 'pending',
  [[PromiseResult]]: 'undefined' }
```

And ends without doing anything else, so I thought it was doing nothing. In my not fully reduced code shown here, I also had a couple of typos within the forEach promise whose errors were getting suppressed.

Comment: In the mongo shell when you type `db` what does it show?

Comment: Is your syntax correct about using the Promises? See these [examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/find/) at the  NodeJS Driver API.

Comment: @prasad_ typing in db in the mongo shell shows "enwiki". I think the syntax is correct using the Promises, though not 100% sure. I could try the await version tomorrow and see if that changes anything.

Comment: When I run that code verbatim using node v16.5 and mongo node driver 4.0.1, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The above code does work and it just didn't seem like it did. In my case, I think it was a combination of error suppression that I wasn't seeing and this weird node debugger behaviour that led me to believe it wasn't working. I would love an explanation for why this debugger behaviour is happening and how to avoid/fix it though.